# How can I convert an Android app to an app for Ubuntu for phones?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

How can I change from commercially developed app(XXX.APK) for android phone(ex, GalaxyS, GalaxyNexus,etc) to App for phone installed ubutun OS?

( How can I change android APK to app that can be used in Ubuntu phone? )
- Once ubuntu for phone is installed , it is automatically changed? or it is needed any other tool or procedure.
- If tool is needed, let me know tool name and procedures . plz send user manual too.

Comment: Hi kwanbae kim, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I've edited this post to only include your first question. Go ahead and post your two other questions in two other separate question posts. You can see the old version of this post by clicking the date next to "edited" above.

Comment: I don't think is as simple as hitting a button that says "Convert to Ubuntu for Phones app", even though it's based on Android they use different SDKs. "If tool is needed, let me know tool name and procedures . plz send user manual too." - *I don't think this part has an answer yet*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change native android app to ubuntu phone without porting source code Because both have entirly diffrent API. In the case of html5 apps, you can use same code for both android and ubuntu phone.